# When listening to the arrow keys being pressed should I do this on the <body> or <html>

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have:

```
<html data-ng-keydown="$broadcast('keydown',$event)">

<body data-ng-keydown="$broadcast('keydown',$event)">
```

Both work.  However would it be better to do it on the `<body>` or the `<html>` or is it the same ?

Comment: Event anyway bubbles and there is only one step from body to html. So the difference is not significant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on what you're looking to achieve - based on your example I would say neither:

There's no data being passed around so you're looking for a globally `$broadcast` event to then listen for a callback somewhere in your App. If you're looking to do this, I'd highly recommend using `$watch` inside your Controller(s) and watch for Model changes:

```
$scope.$watch('myModel', function() {
  // callback when changed
});
```

This will take any events into consideration and will watch for Model changes, which means you're not limited to just keydown events.

When developing "the Angular way", I'd suggest forgetting about DOM and concentrate on your data and `$scope` - that way you can tightly control what's happening and save polluting your app with global `$broadcast` events. Angular will manipulate the DOM effortlessly for you, so setup your `$scope` accordingly and let it do the hard work.

Comment: Todd. I am not sure watching for model changes will help. I want to watch for a press of the right or left arrow.

Comment: @Melina if you're not binding a Model or in need of a Controller, then I suggest writing regular JavaScript to overcome your goals. A lot of developers try convert all their perfectly good code to "Angular code" and this further complicates things (not to mention wastes time and causes breaking changes in future versions). I believe in keeping things simple, so if you really don't need an MVC-based solution for this - just use JavaScript the same way you would without Angular.

Comment: My application is already 99% Angular. I just need the one way to catch a user clicking a right or left button on a screen. I do have a problem because when I check the $event value in the controller I can't see which key code was clicked?

Comment: @Melina If you can overcome it without left/right then you're setup for a more scalable solution - devices don't have left and right buttons the same way desktop does. Appreciate your app may not need to support devices, but it ensures future scalability. If you're set on using the `$broadcast`, then I would opt for the `<body>` tag as it's further down the DOM tree than `<html>`. Good luck!